# What is the file .sconsign.dblite for?

Tags: scons

What would happen if I delete it?

Should I put it under version control?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `.sconsign.dblite` file is a temporary database used by SCons to keep file signatures to speed up future builds. If you delete it, SCons will recreate it (and your next build might take slightly longer because of that). It should not be put under version control.

Comment: Re "your next build might take slightly longer": It could actually take significantly longer if you have an expensive build process, because scons uses the sconsign file to track what intermediates or build processes have and haven't changed, and without that, it will have to rebuild everything.