# How can we parse .sconsign.dblite file?

Tags: build-process, scons

From this : [What is the file .sconsign.dblite for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867783/what-is-the-file-sconsign-dblite-for)
I understand that it is a database.

I am interested to see the contents of it. How can it be parsed?
Is there any standard tool available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation of SCons contains a command-line tool named "sconsign", which can be used to output the contents of the signature database in a more human-readable format.
If you're under Linux/Unix, check its MAN page please (man sconsign).

Comment: Note that the command-line tool "sconsign" mentioned above is actually a Python script which requires some setup in order to run it.